# How to import multiple NodeJS packages together?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const metascraper = require('metascraper')([
  require('metascraper-author')(),
  require('metascraper-date')(),
  require('metascraper-description')(),
  require('metascraper-image')(),
  require('metascraper-logo')(),
  require('metascraper-clearbit')(),
  require('metascraper-publisher')(),
  require('metascraper-title')(),
  require('metascraper-url')()
])
```

I have the following code, but `const` doesn't work so I have to use `import`

```
import metascraper from 'metascraper';
import title from 'metascraper-title';
import image from 'metascraper-image';
...
```

This does not work as expected and returns undefined - how can I import all those libraries underneath `metascraper` using `import`. Importing them manually with their own name does not work.

```
 (async () => {
      try {
        // Use the got library to fetch the website content.
        const targetUrl = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-05-24/as-zenefits-stumbles-gusto-goes-head-on-by-selling-insurance';
        const { body: html, url } = await got(targetUrl);
        // Extract the metadata from the website content.
        const metascraper = await metascraper(title(),{ html, url });
      
        // Return the metadata as JSON
        console.log(JSON.stringify(metascraper));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })()
```

Comment: maybe calls to functions like ``title()`` are also async? that is to say you can try to replace ``await metascraper(title(),{ html, url });`` with ``await metascraper(await title(),{ html, url });``

Comment: Your original code with the `require` calls actually executes all those functions. Your code with the `import` declarations doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import got from "got";

import _metascraper from "metascraper";
import title from "metascraper-title";
import image from "metascraper-image";
import author from "metascraper-author";
// ...

const metascraper = _metascraper([title(), image(), author()]);

try {
  // Use the got library to fetch the website content.
  const targetUrl = "https://wesbos.com/scoped-github-access-token/";
  const { body: html, url } = await got(targetUrl);
  // Extract the metadata from the website content.
  const metadata = await metascraper({ html, url });

  // Return the metadata as JSON
  console.log(metadata);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I use this in practice? I just updated the question details

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more complete (and working) example!